# how i can inherit mail.thread class

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

TypeError: The model "workflow.example" specifies an unexisting parent class "mail.thread"
You may need to add a dependency on the parent class' module.

```
    _name = 'workflow.example'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread']
    _columns = {
        'abc':fields.char('abc', size=20),
        'state': fields.selection([
        ('new','New'),
        ('assigned','Assigned'),
        ('negotiation','Negotiation'),
        ('won','Won'),
        ('lost','Lost')], 'Stage', readonly=True, track_visibility='onchange'),
        'field_1': fields.char('Field_1', size=20),
        'field_2': fields.char('Field_2', size=16),        
    }

 workflow_example()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error message says, that you have to update you __openerp__.py file and add "mail" to "depends" parameter:

```
"depends" : ["base", "mail"],
```

Comment: how can we use user based workflows - pls advise.
if i want to change my above workflows to work it for different users like won button should only be visible/clickable to Adminstrator...how shall i do this?